# Adding name to summarised across columns using custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use a custom function and return columns with an added "_cat_mean" to each column.

In the code below "$cat_mean" is added and I can't select it by that name.

```
summarise_categories <- function(x) { 
  tibble(
    cat_mean = round(mean(x) * 2) / 2
  )
  }

iris_summarised = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(ends_with("Length"), ~summarise_categories(.)))
```

Select columns by the name which is displayed doesn't work

```
iris_summarised %>% 
  select(Species, Sepal.Length$cat_mean)
```

But this works

```
iris_summarised %>% 
  select(Species, Sepal.Length)
```

I want the column to be named "Sepal.Length_cat_mean"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.names` argument in `across` to give new column names.

```
library(dplyr)

summarise_categories <- function(x) { 
    round(mean(x) * 2) / 2
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(ends_with("Length"), summarise_categories, 
           .names = '{col}_cat_mean')) -> iris_summarised

iris_summarised

#  Species    Sepal.Length_cat_mean Petal.Length_cat_mean
#  <fct>                      <dbl>                 <dbl>
#1 setosa                       5                     1.5
#2 versicolor                   6                     4.5
#3 virginica                    6.5                   5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` with `colMeans` and `by`

```
by(iris[-5], iris$Species, function(x) round(colMeans(x) * 2) /2)
```